# Getting a value based on mapping of two columns in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with three columns (id, idcon and value). The id variable is the name of the row, the idcon is the id of the row that it connects to and the value is the value associated with the id column. The dataframe is below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                'idcon' : ['B', 'C', 'A'],
                'value' : [1, 2, 3]})
```

I'm looking to get the value associated with the idcon in the same row as the id. I was able to do this by creating a dictionary of the id to idcon and a dictionary of the id to value and then applying the dictionaries over each row. I was wondering if there is a better (pandas) way to go about doing this. The code and results are below.

```
print(df)
idcon = dict(zip(df.id, df.idcon))
idval = dict(zip(df.id, df.value))
df['conval'] = df.id.apply(lambda x: idval.get(idcon.get(x)))
print(df)

##  id idcon  value
##0  A     B      1
##1  B     C      2
##2  C     A      3
##  id idcon  value  conval
##0  A     B      1       2
##1  B     C      2       3
##2  C     A      3       1
```

Comment: why don't you use `merge`

Comment: Why can't you simple reset the index to `idcon`?

Comment: I could see this being an XY Problem. Why do you need to make this column conval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join` is the simplest way:

```
df.set_index('idcon').join(df.set_index('id')['value'], rsuffix='_idcon')
```

`merge` will also work, but requires renaming columns to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `merge` like this:

```
df.merge(df.loc[:,('id','value')].rename(columns={'id':'idcon','value':'conval'}), on='idcon', how='left')


   id   idcon value conval
0   A     B   1     2
1   B     C   2     3
2   C     A   3     1
```

Answer (score 1):

A `set_index` operation, with `map`, could work as @SerialLazer suggested; you could also use `searchsorted`. Note that the only reason this works is because the values in `idcon` and `id` are the same, just different positions :

```
df["conval"] = df.iloc[df.id.searchsorted(df.idcon), -1].array
df

   id   idcon   value   conval
0   A      B       1    2
1   B      C       2    3
2   C      A       3    1
```

This is @SerialLazer's idea, which works well :

```
df["conval"] = df.idcon.map(df.set_index("id").value)
```